# Firebase signInWithGoogle() wants me to fill the email and password fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, jsx

I have attached the signInWithGoogle() method to a button in the form but instead of opening a popup window it asks to fill the email and password fields?

Here's the config file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'

const config = {
    "All the config data"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({prompt : 'select_account'});
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default firebase
```

Here's the button:

```
<CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
  Sign In  Google
</CustomButton>
```

The custom button:

```
import React from 'react'
import './CustomButton.scss'

function CustomButton({children , otherProps}) {
    return (
        <button className='custom-button'  {...otherProps}>
            {children}
        </button>
    )
}

export default CustomButton
```

When I click the "Sign In with Google" button, it should open a popup but instead I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to move `<CustomButton>` out of the `<form>` element?

Comment: Add the prop for specifying the button type and make the CustomButton type to button

Comment: @PiyushThat would work but I'd lose my styling. Which is my whole point of having a custom component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I didn't destructure the object in the CustomButton props, I just had to change it from this:

```
function CustomButton({children , otherProps})
```

To this:

```
function CustomButton({children , ...otherProps})
```

Comment: And also add type='button' to the button, to get rid of the fill fields prompt.